# Could not load file or assembly ImageMagickNET.dll

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, c#-3.0, imagemagick-convert

I'm getting an exception "Could not load file or assembly 'ImageMagickNET.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found." while implementing using ImageMagick.dll.

How can I over come this exception?

I am using Visual Studio 2010 for development on a windows 7 machine.

ImageMagick version: 1.0.3484.35397

Run time version : v2.0.50727

Answer (score 1):

Add a Reference to the 'ImageMagickNet.dll' found in the 'bin\ReleaseQ8' or 'bin\RealeaseQ16' folders, choose one of them.

After that you have to download the ImageMagick 6.5.3-10 version DLLs for Q8/Q16 because the ImageMagickNet was built to this version. (I found all versions at this link: http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/releases/view/30302 For example, for Q16 download: ImageMagick-6.5.3-10-Q16-windows-dll.exe)

Then install it and copy all DLL files from 'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.5.3-Q16' to your bin folder. Now you should be able to run it properly.